# Jquery sticky function fails on fast scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, sticky, onscroll

I'm using a function within an object to transform the sidepanel to a top panel on scrolling.

Looks like this (i "minified the code and removed the object name"):

```
$(document).on("scroll", vars.stickyNav );

var vars = { ... etc

    undoStick: function() {
        vars.sticked = false; 
        vars.stickyMenu.removeClass('_sticked');

        return vars.stickyMenu.animate({ 'top': '-60px' }, 0, function() {
            vars.clone.css({'left':-32,display:'none'});
        });
    },

    stickyNav: function() {
        if ( ! vars.sticked && vars.stickyHeight <= vars.scrollTop ) {
            vars.sticked = true;

            return vars.stickyMenu.addClass('_sticked').animate({ 'top': '40px'}, 0, function(){
                vars.clone.show(null);
                vars.clone.css('left',0);
            });
        } 
        else if ( vars.sticked && vars.stickyTop >= vars.scrollTop ) {
            return vars.undoStick();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that .. if i scroll very fast from somewehre at the bottom to the top of the page the panel doesn't stick back to the side. If i scroll normal/slow/normal fast it works.

Most of the variables are defined outside of the scroll function. there is an additional scroll function bound to the window which updates the $(window).scrollTop() variable on scroll.

What could be the reason for this behavior? Animate functions are set to 0ms .

PS: There is a css transition ( cubic bezier ).

Comment: It could be due to scroll steps. Would it work if you put a tiny delay on the trigger function?

Comment: How could i do that? setTimeout?

Comment: Looks like it depends on the document height. The higher the document the more errors occur. So too much events fired?

Comment: ok. if i use $(window).scrollTop() instead of the variable filled by the other scroll function it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. If i convert the animation() to css() everthing works fine. Thanks.

Sry, to fast. It works better but not all the time.